# Breast cancer data using Fine Needle Aspiration test or "FNA”

Tags: data-request

I am a statistical modeller. I am looking for a breast cancer dataset with these features:

- age
- sex
- shape and texture of the cells.

I need the number of observations to be between 200 to 2000.

Comment: Sorry, your question is very unclear. What *features*? What is *continuous*? What *margins*? How much data? Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] your question

Comment: @Jan Doggen    I have edited my question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Missing: license, format, number of data points, relationship between input and output parameters, context. Take a step back, read your text **without any assumptions** and you'll see that it is not good enough yet.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you mean by "and so on?" Presumably you don't need to know the patient's favorite ice cream flavor. Please take the time to write out a list of all the features you're seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clean and ready dataset is from UCI Machine Learning Repository

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Diagnostic%29

Unfortunately it doesn't have age and sex.

[image]

Another source of the same data is Kaggle

https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data

you may want to ask on that dataset's discussion page about getting similar data with patient age/sex

https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data/discussion

[image]